# How to calculate a rorate ellipse point's tangent?

Tags: c++, opencv, math, ellipse

I got a rotate ellipse by using fitEllipse, and i want calculate the tangent of the points on this ellipse, i tried this:

```
static Line getTangent(const RotatedRect & ell, const Point & p)
{
    // double rad = ell.angle*CV_PI/180;
    // double a = ell.size.width/2;
    // double b = ell.size.height/2;
    // if(fabs(rad-CV_PI/2)<CV_PI/4)
    // {
    //     rad -= CV_PI/2;
    //     b = ell.size.width/2;
    //     a = ell.size.height/2;
    // }
    double rad = (ell.angle-90)*CV_PI/180;
    double a = ell.size.height/2;
    double b = ell.size.width/2;
    double cr = cos(rad);
    double sr = sin(rad);
    double s = ell.center.x;
    double t = ell.center.y;
    double k = - b*b / (a*a) * ((p.x-s)*cr+(p.y-t)*sr) / (-(p.x-s)*sr+(p.y-t)*cr);
    return Line(k,p); // The line through p with grad k
}
```

the ellipse {center:(523.965, 525.291), size:{444.735 x 662.827}, angle:81.7087} with point p(313, 713) result is right, but ellipse {center:(638.93, 639.36), size:{572.964 x 787.908}, angle:6.27164} with point p(756, 985) result is wrong, i guess it is the angle calculation problem, but i dont know how to solve it. Can someone help me ?

Comment: I noticed you have not accepted answer yet, while it does explain the problem.

Comment: Has the answer become wrong accidentally?

Answer (score 1):

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

You need to check whether point lies outside of ellipse (with opencv function if exists or with ellipse equation)

Comment: It’s not clear (to me) how this offers a solution, even if the image hints at the issue. Can you provide clearer guidance or, better yet, code that helps solve the problem?

Comment: Given point lies inside ellipse, so tangent does not exist. Tangent equation is intended for outer points, and has no sense here.